# Finding in mongo with array of json objects

Tags: json, mongodb

Hello I'm trying to find a set of users in my mongoDB using some json objects.

For instance I have an array of users

```
users = [{name:"Bob", country:"Australia"},{name:"Jimbo",country:"Italy"}]
```

What I've been trying to figure out is how I can query so that I can find both of the users.

I know how to search for one user

```
userModel.findOne({name:"Bob", country:"Australia"})
```

but I am unsure how to use an array of json objects with mongo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try querying with logical query operators!

For example, you might be looking at:

```
userModel.find({
  $or: [
    {name: "Bob", country:"Australia"},
    {name: "Jimbo", country:"Italy"}
  ]
});
```

Source:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/

Comment: ahh thanks for that, i understood how to do that but was more having trouble with how i implement the above with an array but i figured i just do $or: array, your code example helped me come to that understanding thanks you :)

Comment: Fwiw, a good habit to pick up is separating concerns as much as you can. In this case, it would apply to your original one-line query code. Breaking that up into multiple lines makes sense (especially if you consider you might need more than 2 conditions in the future).  Oh yeah, upvote the answer with the arrows on the top left if you want! ^^

Comment: haha i can't upvote don't have enough rep, yea ur right i should of tried to be more specific in the code i showed

Comment: It's alright, pay it forward! You can also [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) the answer.